# Express + Nginx. Can't serve static files

Tags: node.js, express, nginx

This is my project folder

```
/
  public/
    index.html
    main.js
    adaptor.js
    main.css
  node_modules/
    socket.io/
  index.js
```

and this is static file configuration in my index.js

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/node_modules')));
app.get('/', (req, res)=>{
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public', '/index.html'));
})
```

and this is my index.html

```
  <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script src="/adapter.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script src="/main.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

and this is my nginx configuration

```
    location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
    }
```

But I am getting 404 on all the scripts. And an another strange thing is that mime-type on those files is set to `text/HTML`

What am I doing wrong here?

I have a project, with an identical project structure, and it has the same configuration, but it works for it, and it isn't working in this case.

Comment: yes the `__dirname` is `/home/ubuntu` and nginx `root` is set to `/home/ubuntu`

Comment: Can you access the static files with /public/myfile? Also,  there is no need for Nginx to try to serve index.html -- you node app is taking care of this.

Comment: I deleted my comment about Nginx `root` when I remembered you were proxy passing -- Nginx should not be trying to serve any files at all. You can remove the `try_files` and `root` from the config.

Comment: It would be useful to isolate whether the problem is with Express or nginx. If you make a request directly to the Express server can you access the script files?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You don't need to configure Nginx *and* Express to serve static files. Both are capable of doing the job independently, but it is up to you to choose.

For these examples I am assuming the same file structure provided in your question.

In both configurations, load files from / in HTML:

```
<script src="/main.js"></script> <!-- loads from myapp/public/main.js -->
```

## Express as static file server, Nginx as reverse proxy

#### express app

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.use(express.static('public')); // notice the absence of `__dirname`, explained later on

// if the request URL doesn't match anything in the 'public' folder,
// it will start searching here next.
app.use(express.static('some_other_folder'));

// from my testing, express will automatically locate index.html if
// it is in a static folder. Declaring a route is not required.

/* 
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'index.html'));
});
*/

app.listen(8080);

// GET / => index.html
// GET /main.js => main.js
```

*Quick side note*: the use of `__dirname` in `express.static()` is not required. Under the hood (actually, it's [here](https://github.com/expressjs/serve-static/blob/master/index.js) on line 65) , Express uses the native Node.js [path.resolve()](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/path.html#path_path_resolve_paths). From the docs:

> The path.resolve() method resolves a sequence of paths or path segments into an absolute path.

Using `path.resolve(__dirname, 'public')` actually **returns the same** as `path.resolve('public')`. I am thinking that your problem was really telling Nginx to serve static files AND proxy the same requests to Express. OK, on to the rest of my answer.

#### Nginx configuration

```
server {
  listen 8081; # must be different port from Express
  server_name example.com;
  location / {
    # hand ALL requests back to express
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080; 
  }
}
```

## Nginx as static file server, Express as API server

#### Nginx configuration

```
server {
  listen 8081;
  server_name example.com;
  location / {
    root /path/to/website/public;
    index index.html;
    try_files $uri $uri/ @express; # instead of 404, proxy back to express using a named location block;
    # source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15467555/8436941
  }
  location @express {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
  }
}
```

#### Express app

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

// actually, Nginx has already taken care of static files. You can still define other routes for API functions for example.
app.get('/my/api', (req, res) => {/* query database, etc. */});

app.listen(8080);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: hey, thank you, this worked. I used the first configuration. Could you point me to a documentation or something, because I want to understand what was it that I was doing wrong? Like, how not using `__dirname` affected the solution? and the fact that the same configuration works for my personal project, and so many projects that I have done for the company that I work for.

Comment: Coming back to this a while later, I think that your original problem was that Nginx was serving from `/home/ubuntu` and not from the public dir. When asked for `main.js` it would then return a 404 and stop there, never proxying anything to Express. As for your other projects, I can't be sure, but I wonder if they worked because your index.html file loaded assets with `src="/public/main.js"`. Anyway, glad it works :)

Comment: This is the GREATEST ANSWER OF ALL TIME! I was stuck for literally the last 24 hours, barely slept for 3 hours. And then I find this answer. Thank you @ContinuousLoad . None of my routes were accessible, only the main page / was accessible. Now, everything just works fine. Thank you.

Comment: @bozzmob Thank you, I am humbled. It makes my day to hear about long drawn-out problems being resolved. Definitely been there. Also, I heard the tip about using a named block in `try_files` in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15467555/8436941) by Chuan Ma. If you (or anyone) upvoted mine, please upvote that answer too.

Comment: @ContinuousLoad 3 to 4 years later and this answer is still saving lives. I don't think I've seen this clear an explanation of how they handshake, anywhere else. TY!

Answer (score 7):

Removing the `try_files` directive from the **nginx configuration file** solved the issue for me.

Comment: This worked out of all the solutions I tried. Thanks, mate.

Comment: That was my issue as well. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/node_modules')));
```

I think those two lines are the reasons why it raises an error.
Can you delete the second one and give it a try? Maybe your express app sets the primary static serving folder "node_modules" and that is why the app cannot serve your main script files.

Also, I don't think it is good idea to serve node_modules directory as static folder. I think in your setup, "bower" seems more appropriate choice as a javascript package manager.

Thanks

Comment: I am pretty sure the [express docs](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) say this is OK. The first static directories will be searched in order for files. Good point about using a package manager for node_modules.

Comment: +1 on recommending to not server node_modules.  It's a huge directory that can expose tens of thousands of files.  Better to only include the front-end libraries you only need somewhere within your "public" folder.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `.` before the `/` to denote a relative path:

```
<script src="./socket.io/socket.io.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="./adapter.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="./main.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Comment: I have already tried that, and I don't think that's how it supposed to work since the static path is set to `__dirname/public` so `./` doesn't fit with it.

Comment: can you post the full request url that the browser is requesting to?

Answer (score 0):

If you have this structure:

```
myApp
  app.js
  -public/
     -js/
```

In `app.js` you should do like this:

```
self.app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
staticRoutes.forEach(route=> {
            self.app.use(BASEPATH+route,express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
        });
```

where `staticRoutes` is an array like

```
staticRoutes=[
'services/'
'about/'
];
```

and in the html (development)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/util.js"></script>
<a href="/about">About Us</a>
```

while when in production is safer using the full path + protocol.