# Content Security Policy error when using express.static to show file after authentication

Tags: express, nginx, redirect, static

I'm trying to use nginx as a proxy server and use express+passport to authenticate user before showing private/static file(s).

I'm only working with http now (during the development stage). I found [Express + Nginx. Can't serve static files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46692341/express-nginx-cant-serve-static-files) and learned quite some from it but my code is not working.

My nginx settings:

```
http {

    server {
        listen 80;
        root /var/www/html;

        location /private {
            proxy_pass http://myIP4:3000/private; #3000 is the port for express server
            proxy_method GET;
        }
    }
}
```

My express(passport) code is like:

```
 ...
 ...
 #simplified login, real code is longer
 app.use('/login', passport.authenticated('local'),function(req, res){
     res.redirect('/private/index.html');  #if authentication is OK
 });


app.use(function(req,res,next){
    if ((req.url !== '/login') && (!req.isAuthenticated()) ){ #not the login page and not authentication failed
            res.redirect(301,'http://myIP4/login.html');
    }
    else {#if authenticated 
        console.log('authentication OK');        
        express.static("/var/www/html/private/");
    }
});
```

My login API works fine, after I submit the username/password, I could see login successfully. But the redirect has some issues: the browser could not show the destination file: /private/index.html (after login) and /private/test.html (if I type the full url directly in my browser after login successfully).

Browser shows:

```
 Cannot GET /private/index.html
```

Debug of Browser shows:

```
Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at http://myIP4/favicon.ico (“default-src”).
```

I found some posts about setting Content_Secrity_policy but I could not make it working after some try out.

Thanks for your time help!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by changing in the express:

From:

```
express.static("/var/www/html/private/");
```

To:

```
app.use ('/private',express.static('/var/www/html/private'));
```

And it works now.